# Truck will not go when first starting

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, mazda

I have a 1994 Mazda B4000. In the past week the truck has gotten where it will not go from a stop, it simply revs the engine for around 30 seconds. The truck will then jerk and go. It will do this one or two times. Once the truck is warmed up a bit it will run fine. It won't do this unless the truck has been sitting for several hours.

I just checked the transmission fluid and it was at the right level. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: Did you follow the correct procedure for checking the level? some auto boxes require some combination of engine stationary, engine running, cycle through lower gears, shift to reverse then drive then neutral etc otherwise its not a true reading. When was the filter last changed?

Comment: @Solar Mike - Was not aware that there was a correct procedure. Not sure if the filter has ever been changed.

Comment: If it has never been changed, I am betting on needing a fluid filter and flush. That is the easiest and less costly to try before getting into the expensive internals.